# Grouping the data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, pandas-groupby

I've the pandas dataframe like below

[image].

I want to transform this DataFrame into another form like below.

[image]

I've tried groupby functionality in pandas.But could not able to achieve the solution. Please help me with suggestions. Thanks inadvance.

Comment: Avoid adding images for the datasets. Add an actual data sample so thats its easier to replicate

Comment: @RoshanSanthosh, I understand. But the above are the outputs. So just placed as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
e=df.groupby(['Country','City'])['Rating'].mean()

pd.DataFrame(e)
```

This would look like

[image]

Comment: @RoshanSanthose, In fact I had this solution ready. But my concern was to get exact output as I mentioned in my question (there should only one cell for India). It think it's not possible right? What do you think?

Comment: If you have multiple-index, then you can